# Strange behaviour on a list with 100000 elements

Tags: python

I have joined Standford online course on Algorithms design and now I'm solving the first programming question.

> The [**file**](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/IntegerArray.txt) contains all the 100,000 integers between 1 and 100,000
>   (including both) in some random order(no integer is repeated). Your
>   task is to find the number of inversions in the file given (every row
>   has a single integer between 1 and 100,000). Assume your array is from
>   1 to 100,000 and i-th row of the file gives you the i-th entry of the
>   array.

*Update: I have found that my code works only for the 2^n case. Problem is in the code, not Python. I have updated the code, now it work fine and I have done the quiz. Thanks to all who helped*

Fixed code is:

```
 def merge_count_split (a, b):
        c = []
        inv = 0
        i=0
        j=0
        for k in range( len(a) + len(b) ):
                if i < len(a) and j < len(b):
                        if a[i] < b[j]:
                                c.append(a[i])
                                i += 1
                        elif a[i] > b[j]:
                                c.append(b[j])
                                inv += len(a)-i
                                j += 1
                elif i == len(a):
                        c.append(b[j])
                        j += 1
                elif j == len(b):
                        c.append(a[i])
                        i += 1
        return c, inv

def count_inv (data):
        n = len(data)
        if n == 1:
                return data, 0
        a, x = count_inv(data[:n/2])
        b, y = count_inv(data[n/2:])
        c, z = merge_count_split(a,b)
        return c, x + y + z

with open('IntegerArray.txt') as f:
        array = [int(line) for line in f]
        print count_inv(array)[0]
```

This program works fine for small arrays, but for the large array from the question it prints array of **65536** numbers in proper order, not 100000, as I expect. It omits numbers at random places.

What is the reason for this unexpected behaviour of python?

Comment: it's some other property of the list (not it's length) that's causing that behaviour.

Comment: @katrielalex, what is wrong with that?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, small lists are processed fine.

Comment: @Sergey Filkin: *sigh* it's some other property of the list (not it's length) that's causing that behaviour.

Comment: @Sergey Filkin: a baseball bat might be effective for a _small_ baseball, but not for the moon. But wait, aren't they both balls?

Comment: @nightcracker the problem is that merge_count_split(a,b) treat a and b  as of equal size. But it's not always true. My stupid.

Comment: On a side note, an style advising is to use 4 spaces for indenting Python code, not 8 spaces or tab characters.

Comment: @jsbueno, personally I prefer 4 spaces per tab, but vim's default is 8. I haven't customized it yet.

Comment: Avoi d using tabs at all -set your editor to use spaces instead of tab - check PEP 8 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for additional styling hints - but spacing and tabs are more important because they affect other people, and yours own, ability to edit your code properly without hitting indentantion erros due to invisible characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `n = len(a)` and merging only `n * 2` times, you truncate `b` if it's longer than `a`.

This partially explains the striking fact that you have 2 ** 16 items in the resulting list.

Comment: My code is for an array of even length, that is bisected on each iteration. Again, small arrays are processed fine.

Comment: @SergeyFilkin, 100000 is even, but is 100000 / 2 even? 100000 / 4? 100000 / 8? 100000 / 16? 100000 / 32 ...?